# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $ionicModal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I'm working on a Ionic application and including a modal view:

```
    app.controller('StepMapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal){
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('template/modal.html', {
         scope: $scope
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });

      $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show()
        $scope.imgUrl = "http://placekitten.com/g/500/800"
      }
});
```

I'm following this template: http://codepen.io/mikekoro/pen/dPYWvQ

When I open the page I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $ionicModal
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24qProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24q%20%3C-%20%24ionicModal
    at ionic.bundle.js:9007
    at ionic.bundle.js:12475
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:12602)
    at ionic.bundle.js:12480
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:12602)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12629)
    at ionic.bundle.js:12481
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:12602)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12629)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:12650)
```

This is my modal, template/modal.html

```
 <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">View Image</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="modal.hide()">Close</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding" scroll="false">

      <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" delegate-handle="zoom-pane" class="zoom-pane" min-zoom="1" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false">   
      <img ng-src="{{imgUrl}}">
    </ion-scroll>

    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

I was including an old ionic version into my app.

Thank you for replies

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your setup? Are you separating your code into `app.js`, `controllers.js` etc? Have you forgotten to define your angular module, or did you just forget to copy it into your code snippet above?

Either way, if you're using `app.controller...`, you need to declare your Angular module as a variable, like this:

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);

app.controller('StepMapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal){
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('template/modal.html', {
         scope: $scope
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
      });

      $scope.openModal = function() {
        $scope.modal.show()
        $scope.imgUrl = "http://placekitten.com/g/500/800"
      }
});
```